# Magento: Regenerating the categories' URLs Programatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I had created some categories programatically. It seems like some of the category's URLs could not be created in URL rewrite table, although each category already contains a URL key.

I tried to update the category but still URL rewrite manager missing some categories.

Is it possible to regenerate the URLs of all the categories ?

I can't delete the categories since lots of products have already been added and attached to those categories.

Thanks

Comment: if I had a problem in the code, I would definitely paste the piece here, but it's not directly about the code. Please reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.

Thanks to this [article](http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento)

We actually have to reindex the catalog_url components.

It can be done from Index Management magento admin.

Programatically it can be done as

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_url');
$process->reindexAll();
```

By running this process, it regenerates all the URLs of the products and categories.
Hope it may help someone.